# Using search scope in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a document library in a separate sub-site having a content type associated with it, now i want to search document(using Out Of Box search web part) from this library based on their content type, so i have created a search scope(from site collection administration > search scope) then added a rule that Content Type="name of my content type". but the search scope doesn't show any result, count remains 0.

Data has been successfully crawled as it is getting searched with their title, so there is no problem with crawling, what could be the problem? please suggest.

Comment: Is your scope repopulated? It may take up to 15 minutes to repopulate new scope definition. I would also try to start full reindexing.

Comment: yes i have checked after it got updated count still comes as 0, there is also another issue occurring that after crawling the content source the crawled properties are not getting created for site columns specified in content type.